# Localhost Magento 2 — How to access on network?

Tags: localhost, ubuntu

I have installed **Magento 2** to **run locally (127.0.0.1)** on a computer running Ubuntu.
Eveything works and I am hoping to now be able to access it from other PC's on the network.

> Can anyone point me in the right direction on what to do?

Installing Magento 2 was difficult, so I don't want to mess that up (used Linux for the first time to install magento)

Edit to make clear my goals:

- Be able to access magento admin (installed on a machine running ubuntu) from other pc's on the network. Magento is currently configured as 127.0.0.1.

I assume I need to change 127.0.0.1 to the LAN IP somewhere (an apache config, and/or the sqldb?)

Comment: Use your `system IP` address instead of `127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your localhost to system ip, such as

UPDATE core_config_data SET value = 'http://192.160.0.0/magento23/' WHERE path LIKE 'web/secure/base_url';

UPDATE core_config_data SET value = 'http://192.160.0.0/magento23/' WHERE path LIKE 'web/unsecure/base_url';

Finally, cache:clean and cache:flush

Comment: i tried it, but magento site doesn't opening via Ip address in Ubuntu 22. but using virtual domain server name like `http://hello.com` its works. can you post full details about access magento site via ip address lan